# check if a record exists in any of the different tables in a database

Tags: mysql

I am at a situation where i need to check if a particular record exists in any of the tables in the database.

All the tables have same structure but the reason to create different tables is just to categorize them.

I am trying to make a query which checks if the particular records exists in any of the tables. Having a look at UNION i guess it will be a overhead as i have around 100 different tables with some of them having 300 thousand records...

Could someone guide in right direction... It also wondered me how Google search engine doing things...

Thank you

Comment: Why not use a new column called `category` to categorize them?

Comment: If the tables are the same, why not create a category field and use one big table?

Comment: I should have done it but now i am way to far to revert the things :(

Comment: Then you need to loop through all the tables!

Comment: is there no other way...

Comment: i bet many of us come across situations like this, i dont know why someone downvote it...

Comment: You can still put everything together in one table and use views to "recreate" the old ones. Have a look at [updateable views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html) in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only need to do this once, you can generate a bunch of SQL statements that you can run and see if any of them actually returns something. Obviously replace the stuff in curly brackets with whatever you need. If you need to do this repeatedly, then definitely look into something else.

```
 SELECT CONCAT( 'SELECT {something} from', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , 'where {something_else};' ) 
AS statement FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE 
   table_schema = '{database_name}'
   table_name LIKE '{myprefix}%';
```

Answer (score 0):

First run below query.
For example, I have database named test. It contains 5 tables which are having same structure.
SELECT CONCAT('select * from ',table_name, ' where col_name=value',' union') FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE table_schema='test'

Here, You can get one result set like this

SELECT * FROM messaging UNION
SELECT * FROM messaging1 UNION
SELECT * FROM messaging2 UNION
SELECT * FROM messaging3 UNION
SELECT * FROM messaging4 UNION
SELECT * FROM messaging5 **UNION**

Run this result set and then you can get required  records from all tables

Note: remove 'UNION' at end of query.

Please let me know if you have any issues.